# ListBoxes in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an assignment where the user will enter numbers into a list box. When the user is done entering numbers, it will compute the average and the standard deviation.(Our professor does not want us to use built in standard deviation functions) The program will have a context menu and these are the guidelines for creating the menu: You must create a subroutine called SetMenu. It is used to enable and disable context menu based on the contents of the list. When the list is empty,Clear is disabled. When the list has at least one number in it,Clear is  enabled. When nothing is selected, Delete Item is disabled. When something is selected, Delete Item is enabled. 
That is where I need help, creating that subroutine.

Here is my code:

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form1

Private Sub AddBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddBtn.Click
    ListBox.Items.Add(InputBox.Text)
    InputBox.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub ComputeBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComputeBtn.Click
    Dim sum, x, number, numberSum, subtractedNum As Integer
    Dim average, insideRoot, squaredRoot As Double


    For x = 0 To ListBox.Items.Count - 1
        ListBox.SelectedIndex = x

        number = Integer.Parse(ListBox.SelectedItem.ToString)
        sum = sum + number
        average = sum / ListBox.Items.Count
    Next
    AverageLbl.Text = average.ToString

    For x = 0 To ListBox.Items.Count - 1
        ListBox.SelectedIndex = x
        number = Integer.Parse(ListBox.SelectedItem.ToString)

        subtractedNum = CInt((number - average) ^ 2)
        numberSum = numberSum + subtractedNum
        insideRoot = (numberSum / (ListBox.Items.Count - 1))
        squaredRoot = insideRoot ^ (1 / 2)
    Next
    DeviationLbl.Text = squaredRoot.ToString("N2")

End Sub

Private Sub ClearMenu_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ClearMenu.Click
    ClearMenu.Enabled = False
    SetMenu()
    ListBox.Items.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteMenu_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DeleteMenu.Click
    ListBox.Items.Remove(ListBox.SelectedItem)
End Sub

Private Sub InputBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles InputBox.TextChanged
    If IsNumeric(InputBox.Text) And InputBox.Text <> "" Then
        AddBtn.Enabled = True
    Else
        AddBtn.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SetMenu()
    'Need help here
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I need help creating the subroutine named SetMenu. I need to enable the ClearMenu Item if there is at least one item in the list box. And I need to enable the DeleteMenu Item if there is something selected in the list box.

Comment: Sounds like you need to check ListBox.Items.Count.  If it's 0, disable the Clear button.  If it's > 0, enable the Clear button.  Then check ListBox.SelectedIndex.  If it's -1, disable Delete.  If it's >= 0, enable Delete.

Comment: What are the conditions that I need to put in the If statement?.. I tried doing If ListBox.Items.Count > 0 then ClearMenu.Enabled = True and that statement didn't work for me and therefore, I do not know what would my condition be.

Comment: @Capellan Thank you. It worked for the Delete Menu Item, but nor for the Clear Menu Item. It works but in order for the clear menu item to enable you have to click on an item in the list box

Comment: @StephanieCorrea Try `ClearMenu.Enabled = (ListBox.Items.Count > 0)` that will enable the Clear menu if there are items in the ListBox and disable it if there are no items.

Comment: @Blackwood I tried that as well and it will only enable it if I click on something in the list box

Comment: @StephanieCorrea you have to make sure the code is executed in order for it to work. For example, execute it when the form loads and again every time something happens that might add or delete a ListBox item.

Comment: Are you calling SetMenu when you add or remove an item from the ListBox?

Comment: @Capellan I just fixed it. I wasn't calling it when I added items to the list box. Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Private Sub toggleContextMenuItems()

    ClearToolStripMenuItem.Visible = (ListBox1.Items.Count > 0)

    DeleteToolStripMenuItem.Visible = (ListBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)

End Sub
```

Then call this method when needed.